# Dialing Number with Extension is Not Working in some device like Nexus 4

Tags: android, phone-call, android-dialer

I am trying to dial the number with extension:

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:0008001009009,1");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,number);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

This is working in some devices, but for some devices like Nexus 4 its not working. Its not taking the extension number.

`PhoneNumberUtils.WAIT` i.e  " ; " is working , but in this case input is required from user.

`PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE` i.e " , " is for Automatic dialing the extension.

I want to dial the extension automatically. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending `ACTION_DIAL` intent to check what is the number being displayed on other devices.

Else append with `+` on the number and invoke `ACTION_DIAL` or `ACTION_CALL`.

Comment: ACTION_DIAL  will display the number without extension number and appending + will also not work